# How does this operator [ ] overloading works in this case?

Tags: c++, overloading

I stumbled upon this class:

```
class Vec3f
{
    ...
    float x, y, z;
    ...
};

inline float operator[](const int index) const
{
    return (&x)[index];
}

inline float& operator[](const int index)
{
     return (&x)[index];
}
```

The class is using the [] to access to x, y, z values as in an array so that
v[0] is the value in x,  v[1] is the value in y, v[2] is the value in z, but

- How does the return statement working?
- Is it correct to read it like: "get the value in the address specified by index starting from the address of x"?
- Do (&x) must be in parenthesis, otherwise it would return the value of the address of x[index], isn't it?

Comment: This code is relying on how a particular compiler works. Technically this is not valid code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically this is not valid code.

But what is happening:

```
// Declare four variables
// That are presumably placed in memory one after the other.
float x, y, z;
```

In the code:

```
return (&x)[index];

// Here we take the address of x (thus we have a pointer to float).
// The operator [] when applied to fundamental types is equivalent to 
// *(pointer + index)

// So the above code is
return *(&x + index);
// This takes the address of x. Moves index floating point numbers further
// into the address space (which is illegal).
// Then returns a `lvalue referring to the object at that location`
// If this aligns with x/y/z (it is possible but not guaranteed by the standard)
// we have an `lvalue` referring to one of these objects.
```

Its easy to make this work and be legal:

```
class Vec3f
{
    float data[3];
    float& x;
    float& y;
    float& z;

    public:
        float& operator[](const int index) {return data[index];}

        Vec3f()
            : x(data[0])
            , y(data[1])
            , z(data[2])
        {}
        Vec3f(Vec3f const& copy)
            : x(data[0])
            , y(data[1])
            , z(data[2])
        {
            x = copy.x;
            y = copy.y;
            z = copy.z;
        }
        Vec3f& operator=(Vec3f const& rhs)
        {
            x = rhs.x;
            y = rhs.y;
            z = rhs.z;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Comment: Well, it's *legal*, it's just not *correct* (i.e., it may not always do the right thing.)

Comment: Yes, a further research lead me to know this code relies heavily on padding in order to guarantee its functioning, and yes, it may be compiler specific, however I tested it on VS and GCC with/without #pragma pack(push,1) and #pragma pack(pop) and it worked. I do programm mainly in C# so I needed a refresher on operator overloading.  I'll wait for other answers just for the sake of completeness but I agree with yours.

Comment: I guess it's /legal/ only if the class doesn't contain virtual methods (the snippet doesn't show it, but there are no virtual methods on the said class).

Comment: It's "legal" to the extent of being syntactically correct. The `(&x+index)` part is required to work (produce an address) when `index == 0` or `index == 1`, but dereferencing the result when `index != 0` gives undefined behavior. In theory, even forming the address `(x+2)` isn't required to work, but in reality it almost certainly will yield an address with most implementations.

Comment: @piglas16: It is never legal. If it works it is an accidental side affect of the behavior of the compiler. This is nothing you should rely on.

Comment: @greyfade: Its syntactically legal. BUT its semantically not legal. Its undefined behavior.